# 3.3V Conversion

Tags: voltage-level, convert

I'm writing a SPI Master module for my FPGA and I would like test it with my Arduino Uno.
What's the problem? My FPGA has 3.3V logic and Arduino has 5V TTL logic.
So, what's the simplest solution to convert 5V TTL logic into 3.3V logic?

I know this topic has been already discussed in many sites but I can't find an unified answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Logic level Converter boards

Comment: Just about any 5V powered IC will take 0-3.3V and output 0-5V.
[Like this one for example](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/SN74AC241N/296-4308-5-ND/375881)

Comment: If you don't need the 16 MHz clock speed, running your Arduino at 8 MHz/3.3v is an option.  Or there are chips that run far faster at that voltage.  Or you can use level conversion, either fully push/pull or low side with pullup - it's not really possible to pick the best solution without considering context that is missing from your question.

Comment: Use a 3.3v Arduino or NodeMCU and simplify life.

Comment: You will get better answers (and maybe stop people arguing with each other) if you mention what FPGA you have in mind, and maybe a link to its datasheet, so we can see what its requirements are. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: But just any 3.3V device won't take 5V.

Answer (score 1):

You can get 5, 4 channel bi-directional logic level converters for less than $1 USD [Logic Level Module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/5PCS-IIC-I2C-Logic-Level-Converter-Bi-Directional-Module-5V-to-3-3V-For-Arduino/32216849765.html)

Not only will they "translate" 3.3V to 5V and 5V to 3.3V, but they also work with higher voltages as well. For example, a vehicle with a 12V electrical system to 5V and vice versa works too.

Comment: While this clever circuit will work for some purposes, one should beware that such devices only actively drive low.  The high side output is provided by a pull-up resistor only, typically 10K (though could be smaller).  As a result, it is limited to moderately low speeds and short wire runs in quiet environments.

Comment: The OP asked for the "the simplest solution". My answer is simple and very inexpensive. If you have a simpler method, please share it with us.

Comment: Your answer is indeed simple, but it is not always *suitable*.  The point of my comment was to point out the limitation so that an *informed* decision can be made.  Engineering almost always comes down to such a trade off between needs and costs, so the key to success is *knowledge* rather than blind assumption.  I've used circuits such as you suggest in projects, but I've also had needs which they cannot meet.

Comment: Just like I thought, you don't have a simpler way to level translate.

Comment: If you prefer to shop US instead of ordering from China, both Sparkfun & Adafruit manufacture similar modules.

Comment: -1 If you are going to absolutely beg for a downvote by positioning your suggestion as a contest entry rather than a technical solution limited to some circumstances, you are welcome to one.  As for a "simpler" way, there are circumstances where just a series resistor is enough (one of which is in a Xilinx FPGA app note, no less!).  And there are circumstances where you do not need anything at all.  But as always, **what is suitable depends on the unstated details of the need**.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - If you don't like my answer and have a better one, why won't you answer the question? Comments are for clarifying the question, not answering it.